# Play and stop MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, R.raw.lastmohican);
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I can play this music by one click and with another click music is stopped, but when I click together music does not start. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its solved you should change code for this type

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.seekTo(0);
} else {
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but if you are wondering why the audio will not start back up after you press the button a third time, it is because you are calling `stop()` on the media player when you should be calling `pause()`.  Stop requires you to prepare the media again before you can begin playback. Have a look at the [MediaPlayer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).  If that is not your problem you need to provide a better description.